# Next step to understand Bitcoin Core

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoin-core-development

After compiling Bitcoin Core, what should be my next step to understand the codebase?

I’m a very new contributor and developer.

Comment: Does one of these related topics answer your question: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/37684/5406, https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/92581/5406, https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/41692/5406?

Comment: Yes, they worked out. Thanks